# Time has an offset of two hours on windows container with Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Using Visual Studio 2017, I added Docker support with Windows container to a simple asp.net core application.

When I run the application, the values of DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow are 2 hours later than the expected values. (Instead of 1:00 UTC, it's 3:00 UTC)

If I use Docker with Linux containers, the time is correct.

How is the time managed in the windows container and how can I synchronize it with the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found a post on Moby's github : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37283

It appears to be a bug on windows images where you get the wrong time if your timezone is east of PST. A fix is expected in september 2018.

Answer (score 0):

I will speculate that you live 2 timezones away from Greenwhich.  Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa.  I noticed the time in my docker containers was off from local (but consistent with GMT).  I tried the trick `--env TZ=America/Los_Angeles` and the time in my docker container was off from local but consistent with Los Angeles.

So it seems the solution is to add an argument `--env TZ={your timezone}` to your docker run command.